# boost gzip_compressor and gzip_decompressor

Tags: c++, boost, gzip

I'm using `boost`'s `gzip_compressor` and 'gzip_decompressor' for compressing some string. 
I'm compressing string like this

```
string compressedString;
{
    filtering_ostream out;
    out.push(gzip_compressor(gzip_params(gzip::best_compression)));
    out.push(boost::iostreams::back_inserter(compressedString));
    out.write(stringToBeCompressed.c_str(), stringToBeCompressed.size());
}
```

It works fine, but I can't to decompress it. Here is my code

```
std::string decompressedString;
{
    filtering_ostream out;
    out.push(gzip_decompressor());
    out.push(boost::iostreams::back_inserter(decompressedString));
    out.write(compressedString.c_str(), compressedString.size());
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found out a way of this problem. Here is the working code.

Compressing part

```
std::string compressedString;
{
    filtering_ostream compressingStream;
    compressingStream.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_compressor(gzip_params(gzip::best_compression)));
    compressingStream.push(boost::iostreams::back_inserter(compressedString));
    compressingStream << stringToBeCompressed;
    boost::iostreams::close(compressingStream);
}
```

Decompressing part

```
std::string decompressedString;
{
    boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream decompressingStream;
    decompressingStream.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
    decompressingStream.push(boost::iostreams::back_inserter(decompressedString));
    decompressingStream << stringToBeDecompressed;
    boost::iostreams::close(decompressingStream);
}
```