# Copy and archive/compress text files using C++

Tags: c++, compression, filestream, archive

My task is simple.  Whenever I run my C++ program

```
$ ./myprogram
```

I want to search for all all source (*.cpp) files in the CWD, and then make copy of them in the directory `./output`, and then create some sort of compressed archive file.  I don't care what type of compression or archive format, just anything to put them all together into a single file.

Currently, I'm using the following function:

```
int archiveFiles(string destinationFile) {
    int ret;    
    ret = system( ("tar -cf " + destinationFile + " ./*.cpp").c_str() );
    ret = system( ("gzip " + destinationFile).c_str() );
    return ret;
}
```

with the call `archiveFiles("output");`

But I would prefer *not* to use system calls.  I would rather do the copying/archiving/compressing in `myprogram` itself. I also prefer not to use special libraries, if possible.

Anyway to do this with just standard library elements?

Comment: at least you must use `zlib` or similar to create the archive

Comment: No, there are no c++ standard mechanisms that support these compression features. You may have a look at [lzma](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) or similar libraries that support file compression mechanisms.

Comment: So if I can summarize: "yes, I know about those round wheels that other people use, but I'm going to invent some new triangular wheels anyway!" Does that about cover it?

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm not trying to reinvent any wheels--at least, I don't mean to. Are you saying that the `system(...)` way of doing it is actually perfectly fine? If so, then I'm happy to stick with it.

Comment: I'm saying that "special libraries" would be the right way, executing an external program second best, and inventing your own a *distant* third.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no C++ standard library element for doing this. You must either use a special library, use an external application or develop your own text compressor.

I guess the closest you get to using a "standard" library is to use the Boost libraries. I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100059/boost-gzip-compressor-and-gzip-decompressor) and think that Boost may have support for gzip.

Answer (score 0):

Use [libtar](http://www.feep.net/libtar/), a tar file manipulator.